# Display Race Lap times and position with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to plot a line graph with Chart.js that shows trends from a series of lap times.

This is my (example) Data:

```
const datetime = ["2021-02-08 15:01:50", "2021-02-08 16:01:50", "2021-02-08 17:01:50"];
const position = ["8", "8", "7"];
const laptime = ["1:32.599", "1:32.300", "1:31.000"];
```

And here is my chart.js Code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: datetime, // list of races,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Lap Time",
      fill: false,
      data: times,
    },{
      label: "Position",
      fill: false,
      data: position ,
    }]
  },
  options: {
      scales: {
          xAxes: [{
              display: true,
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                  unit: 'hour',
                  round: 'hour',
                  unitStepSize: 1
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    parser: 'm:s.SSS',
                    unit: 'seconds',
                    unitStepSize: 1,
                    displayFormats: {
                        'seconds': 'm.s'
                    }
                },
                ticks: {
                    min: '1:0.0',
                    max: '2:0.0'
                }
            }]
            }
        }
        });
```

I want to have two Datasets every Hour one representing the Lap Time and the other the Position

Comment: This is how the Diagramm currently looks like, Data is right but no points, no bar, and no errors also... [Diagram](https://ibb.co/xMZFQ1c)

Comment: This question needs to be more specific. Tell you what, take [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/QWGKbaB) I made long time ago and try to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Hello thank you very much for the CodePen, with this I could solve my problem and will edit the Question soon. Regards Roger